# Using bind mount causes some programs to error with "Only root can mount"

Tags: hard-drive, mount, fedora-17

I have an SSD for my boot, and some of my media directories (i.e. Pictures) are still on a regular hard drive.

I mount the disk:

```
/dev/sdb1 /data ext3 noatime 0 2
```

And then mount the partitions:

```
/data/me/Pictures /home/me/Pictures none bind
```

I can CD into the directories, the file manager can show me the files, but some programs (for example, the Fedora 17 default Image Viewer) produce an error saying that only root can mount the partition - which is already mounted.

Is this a bug in the way programs access the file system, or am I using the bind mount incorrectly?

Comment: Why bother with a bind mount when a symbolic link will do?

Comment: I don't want my backups to traverse symlinks, but I do want the Pictures/ backed up.  But I don't really have a good reason for doing it this way other than I was trying something new.

Comment: If your backup is traversing symlinks, instead of just backing them up, fix it or get a backup program that doesn't suck. :)

Comment: I think this is getting off-track - I'm curious why this happens, and if the way I'm using bind mounts is incorrect or if it's a problem with certain programs.